# Prevent DB-Calls while Django initializes

Tags: django, django-models

In Django, running queries from the module-level in e.g. `models.py` is discouraged for good reasons.

1. Since this means your queries are run on-initialization, the state of your DB-machinery is basically unknown while the queries run.
2. It makes testing hard/impossible (for the reason '1').
3. It slows loading your application
4. DB (connection, or other) errors that occur on-load will be "remembered forever"

Unfortunately, it's not clear to me how to generally prevent it, which means by Murphey's law that it will happen.

Say I have something like the below (but with a slightly less obvious name for the offending function)... how can I prevent this generally (i.e. fail-hard)?

```
# models.py

class MyModel(models.Model):
    somefield = models.IntegerField(choices=get_something_from_db())
```

Note that the above is always executed, even if you use Django 1.8's callable choices all choices are evaluated for model-validation.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself, but you can probably do this with a couple of signals.

First, you can prevent DB connections by listening to the connection-created signal:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#connection-created

By listening to this signal (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#listening-to-signals)
you can raise an exception to prevent your code from actually doing anything.

Secondly you can tell if you got a request, by listening to the request-started signal:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#request-started

On the receiver for this signal, you can **remove** the listener for the "connection-created" signal, so database connection can now be created.
As a final step, remove the listener to the "request-started" signal (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#disconnecting-signals), so you have zero impact of this code for the remainder of your program.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As I indicated (admittedly, tersely) "even if you use Django 1.8's callable choices..." by which I mean [1] you are correct that in the provided code example the error is in the parentheses, but this is a requirement for pre-django 1.8 and [2] in Django 1.8 the parentheses are still added by Django's model validation even if you leave them out.  However, my real question is: how can I at a single point make such DB calls trigger an error, so I can automatically find them and remove them?